# How to pas ISO 8601 formatted date value in GET Request

Tags: api, parsing, datetime, object

I am working on lob.com letters API. Using Postman application to test the API, facing the following error:
[Postman Application to test Lob's API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z0RU.png)

The parameter "date_created" want date value in ISO 8601. I am passing the value in specified format but api returns the response having error: "date_created must be an object".

Need help!

Comment: Basically date_created has "from" and "to" value also and may be that's the reason it wants date object to be passed.
Is anybody knows how to pas such parametric values (as a object)  in GET Request?

Comment: Try passing the date as UTC 2016-10-23T17:20:35.093Z.

Answer (score 4):

In pre request script compute current date and set it to environment variable then you can pass it in your request body. A bit of code will look like this:

**Pre Request**

```
var date = new Date().toISOString();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("date",date);
```

**Request Body**

```
// Other attribs....
"date_created" : "{{date}}"
```